# Configure Turnip and Database_cleaner

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, database-cleaner

I'm using [Turnip](https://github.com/jnicklas/turnip) and Ruby on Rails. I have scenarios with and without using javascript. I want to use the `transaction` DatabaseCleaner strategy for the non-javascript scenarios and the `truncation` strategy for scenarios marked by `@javascript`, `@selenium` and etc.

I'm using following solution for [Rspec Features](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec)

```
config.around(:each, :js => true) do |ex|
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  ex.run
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
end
```

But it doesn't work in Turnip case. What is the best way to make it works as I expected? Or in other words how to specify turnip scenario marked by `@javascript` (or `@selenium` and etc) tag in `config.before`?

Answer (score 5):

By inspecting the [code of Turnip](https://github.com/jnicklas/turnip/blob/master/lib/turnip/capybara.rb) I yield such config options

```
 config.around(:each, type: :feature, javascript: true) do |example|
   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
   example.run
   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
 end
```

In this case strategy is set to `truncation` when scenario is tagged by `@javascript` tag like following:

```
  @javascript
  Scenario: Viewing users
    Given the following users:
```

But in my soultion when you want to use for example Selenium in one scenario you should not replace `@javascrtipt` tag by `@selenium` tag but add `@selenium` tag after `@javascript` tag like following

```
  @javascript @selenium
  Scenario: Viewing users
    Given the following users:
```